# Regular expression to remove line breaks

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am a complete newbie to Python, and I'm stuck with a regex problem. I'm trying to remove the line break character at the end of each line in a text file, but only if it follows a lowercase letter, i.e. `[a-z]`. If the end of the line ends in a lower case letter, I want to replace the line break/newline character with a space.

This is what I've got so far:

```
import re
import sys

textout = open("output.txt","w")
textblock = open(sys.argv[1]).read()
textout.write(re.sub("[a-z]\z","[a-z] ", textblock, re.MULTILINE) )
textout.close()
```

Comment: If there is no `$` and no `^` in a RE, there is no need of tag `re.MULTILINE`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try

```
re.sub(r"(?<=[a-z])\r?\n"," ", textblock)
```

`\Z` only matches at the end of the string, after the last linebreak, so it's definitely not what you need here. `\z` is not recognized by the Python regex engine.

`(?<=[a-z])` is a [positive lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that checks if the character before the current position is a lowercase ASCII character. Only then the regex engine will try to match a line break.

Also, always use raw strings with regexes. Makes backslashes easier to handle.

Comment: I would replace `\r?\n` with `[\r\n]+` to also hit single `\r`.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, It will also strip blank lines, btw

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Are there still Macs around that use `\r`, and does Python run on them? I thought Apple gave up the `\r` line endings with OS X, but I may be entirely wrong about this.

Comment: Hopefully not.. but you can never know what crappy files are around - there are way too many files containing a mix of `\n` and `\r\n` so I'd expect some `\r` files to still exist, too.

Comment: So `[\r\n]{1,2}` will do , or better according to me: `(\n|\r\n?)` in which possibility of `\r` alone is the third to be tested.

Comment: @eyquem: Definitely the second one: `(?:\n|\r\n?)`, or you might remove two adjacent Unix newlines by accident.

Comment: By the way, there is absolutely no need of raw-string for this RE. And upper `\Z` matches end of string, not lower

Comment: Oh yes. No need of `?:` in yours.

Comment: @eyquem: It is always good practice to use raw strings. Do you know by heart which backslash escapes are necessary and which aren't? This just removes one frequent source of errors. I also always prefer non-capturing parentheses if I don't intend to capture its contents. Not so much for efficiency reasons but for clarity, and because some Python regex operations behave very differently when capturing parens are present. About `\Z` and `\z`, you're right for Python - I just found that Python doesn't implement the usual behaviour that Perl, .NET, PCRE etc. have.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker I am not fond of sentences expressing "always" truths. Personnaly, I prefer not to use raw-string : that forces me to understand what I write and to remember what I understand. There are not so much escapes in regexes, I remember the more frequent ones, the other I verify. It's a matter of taste. I fear that the use of raw-string in RE prevent a newbie to do the efforts to really understand what's going on in the interpretation of a RE by a regex compiler.

Answer (score 3):

Just as an alternative answer, although it takes more lines, I think the following may be clearer since the regular expression is simpler:

```
import re
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as ifp:
    with open("output.txt", "w") as ofp:
        for line in ifp:
            if re.search('[a-z]$',line):
                ofp.write(line.rstrip("\n\r")+" ")
            else:
                ofp.write(line)
```

... and that avoids loading the whole file into a string.  If you want to use fewer lines, but still avoid postive lookbehind, you could do:

```
import re
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as ifp:
    with open("output.txt", "w") as ofp:
        for line in ifp:
            ofp.write(re.sub('(?m)([a-z])[\r\n]+$','\\1 ',line))
```

The parts of that regular expression are:

- `(?m)` [turn on multiline matching]
- `([a-z])` [match a single lower case character as the first group]
- `[\r\n]+` [match one or more of carriage returns or newlines, to cover `\n`, `\r\n` and `\r`]
- `$` [match the end of the string]

... and if that matches line, the lowercase letter and line ending are replaced by `\\1`, which will the lower case letter followed by a space.

Comment: One line `ofp.write(re.sub("(?<=[a-z])(\n|\r\n?)"," ",line)` instead of four lines

Comment: @eyquem: sure, but my point was that avoiding using positive lookbehind might make the code more readable, and that three extra lines might be worth it for that...  Well, I'll add another version anyway.

Answer (score 1):

*my point was that avoiding using positive lookbehind might make the code more readable*

OK. Though, personally, I don't find it's less readable. It's a matter of taste.

In your EDIT:

- First,  **(?m)** is not necessary since **for line in ifp:** selects one line at a time and so there is only one newline at the end of each line's string
- Secondly, **$** as it is placed, has no utility because it will always match the end of the string line.

Any way, adopting your point of view, I found two manners to avoid the lookbehind assertion:

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as ifp:
    with open("output.txt", "w") as ofp:
        for line in ifp:
            ante_newline,lower_last = re.match('(.*?([a-z])?$)',line).groups()
            ofp.write(ante_newline+' ' if lower_last else line)
```

and

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as ifp:
    with open("output.txt", "w") as ofp:
        for line in ifp:
            ofp.write(line.strip('\r\n')+' ' if re.search('[a-z]$',line) else line)
```

the second one is better: only one line , a simple matching to test, no need of groups(), naturally logic

EDIT: oh I realize that this second code is simply your first code rewritten in one line, Longair