# Regular expression to remove two line breaks conditionally

Tags: python, python-re

I'm trying to remove two line breaks character at the end of each line in a text file, but only if it follows a lowercase letter, i.e. [a-z].
I have the following code:

```
import re
text = "I want this \n\nwith one line break \n\nIn this place \nNothing happens \n\nHere\nnothing should\nhappen too."
texts = re.sub(r"(?<=[a-z])\r?\n\n"," ", text)
print(texts)
```

Text that I want to obtain

```
text = "I want this \nwith one line break \n\nIn this place \nNothing happens \n\nHere\nnothing should\nhappen too."
```

With my code nothing changes in the text. My code follows this answered question: [Regular expression to remove line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075247/regular-expression-to-remove-line-breaks) but I am unable to adapt it to two line breaks.

Comment: "if it follows a lowercase" do you mean if it is followed by a lowercase char ? That is the opposite

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need a positive lookahead , not a lookbehind, to have a lowercase char after

```
import re

expected = "I want this \nwith one line break \n\nIn this place \nNothing happens \n\nHere\nnothing should\nhappen too."
text     = "I want this \n\nwith one line break \n\nIn this place \nNothing happens \n\nHere\nnothing should\nhappen too."
texts = re.sub(r"\n\n(?=[a-z])", "\n", text)

print(texts == expected)
```

Comment: The OP did have a look behind. And you are proposing a lookahead (which is correct but your naming is wrong)